# Why is my second scene empty?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have two scenes currently. I want my first scene to transition to the second under certain standards. However it is just giving me a blank screen as my second scene. Please help :)
Heres is the code that spawns the second scene:

```
  for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if playButton.containsPoint(location) {
                self.view?.presentScene(Level2())
                plate.removeFromParent()
                sprite.removeFromParent()
            }
```

and here is the code I have in my second scene. It says I add a sprite but the sprite is not showing up.

```
import Foundation 
import SpriteKit

class Level2 : SKScene {
    var sprite :SKSpriteNode!
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle Sprite1")
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 350, y: 700)
        Level2().addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because all you have is a blank white screen

`Level2().addChild(sprite)` means create a new level2 scene, and add the child sprite.  You want `self.addChild(sprite)`

Comment: I just used self and it still doesn't work:(. Do you know any other possible problems?

Comment: if it doesn't work then it is because your sprite is outside of your scene